# How can I change the value of a single byte using NASM?

Tags: c, assembly, replace, segmentation-fault, nasm

Using NASM, I need to change a character in a string at a given index and print the string in its new form. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
;test_code.asm

        global main
        extern printf
output_str: db "----------"
index: dq 7
main: 
    push rbp
    mov  rdi, output_str
    mov  rax, index
    mov  byte[rdi + rax], 'x'
    xor  rax, rax
    call printf
    pop  rbp
    ret
```

I then compile using:

```
nasm -felf64 test_code.asm && gcc test_code.o -lm
```

and get a seg fault. Would someone please point out the flaw here? I can't seem to find it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- your string is in the `.text` section of the executable, which is read only by default. Either you allocate a buffer on the stack, copy the string and you modify it there, or you put the string in the `.data` section (which is read/write) using the `section` directive. In this last case, notice that the character replacement will be persistent, i.e. even later in the program the string will remain modified;
- if you want to print that string with `printf` it has to be NUL-terminated. Add a `,0` to the end of the `db` line;
- that `mov  rax, index` is wrong - `index` is the *address* of the qword you wrote above, while you actually want to copy in `rax` the datum wrote there; you probably want `mov rax, [index]`.

So, something like

```
;test_code.asm

    global main
    extern printf

section .data
output_str:
    db "----------",0

section .text
index:
    dq 7

main: 
    push rbp
    mov  rdi, output_str
    mov  rax, [index]
    mov  byte[rdi + rax], 'x'
    xor  rax, rax
    call printf
    pop  rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was finally able to get things working after a whole day of struggling!